# SF Symbols Light/Dark Mode

Tags: ios, swift

Its possible to apply a custom tint color to SFSymbols image based on Appearance? By default it goes from black to white and viceversa, but I would like to customize those colors.
In short, this works as expected, switching from light to dark and viceversa, but I need the control of which tint to apply.

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "car")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into how dark mode works and all the ways you can create UIColors that change based on the appearance?

Comment: The only way I can achieve this from my understanding is to uset custom assets and setting those for light and dark appearance. But unsure how to proceed if I'm using SFSymbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var image = UIImage(systemName: "car")?.withTintColor(.systemRed, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
private var imageView: UIImageView?

private func changeImageTint() {
    let tintColor: UIColor = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .systemRed : .systemBlue
    image = image?.withTintColor(tintColor)
    imageView?.image = image
}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    changeImageTint()
}
```

or create a custom color (2 colors) based on userInterfaceStyle and just use that:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var mySymbolColor: UIColor { UIColor.init { $0.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .systemRed : .systemGreen } }
}

button.configuration?.image = UIImage(systemName: "car")?.withTintColor(.mySymbolColor, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: so the only way is to listen to trait collection changes in all places I want to follow this pattern?

Comment: No, you can create a custom color based on the userInterfaceIdiomStyle. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image instance with different appearances for dark and light mode by adding additional variants to the [imageAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624151-imageasset). For example:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "car")!
    .withTintColor(.systemRed, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
let darkImage = UIImage(systemName: "car")!
    .withTintColor(.systemBlue, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    
image.imageAsset?.register(
    darkImage,
    with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
)
```

Now `image` should be automatically rendered red in light mode and blue in dark mode.

Comment: ? why to apply some tint color here? you just can use the light/dark version asset from the imageAsset, they should already have the correct color

Comment: @Godfather: It's just to provide some sample code so you get the idea. You need an image for light mode and another one for dark mode.